# How to save custom attribute value in customer entity table using controller

Tags: magento2, frontend, custom-attributes

I want to save value in customer entity table in this table.

I created one custom field & I want to save value in custom field using controller.

But it is not working.

How is it possible?

**Controller =>**

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Def\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class Def extends Action
{
    protected $customerCollection;

    public function __construct(Context $context,PageFactory $resultPageFactory,Customer $customerCollection,\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $randomletter = 1
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerSession->getCustomerId());
            $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_field');
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('custom_field',$randomletter);
            try
            {                
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you created customer attribute or custom field?

Comment: yes ... @Abdul . I already created using install schema

Comment: can you share your attribute code?

Comment: 'custom_field' => [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'nullable' => false,
                'comment' => 'custom_field',
            ],

Comment: Below solutions is working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Def\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class Def extends Action
{
    protected $customerCollection;

    public function __construct(Context $context,PageFactory $resultPageFactory,Customer $customerCollection,\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $randomletter = 1
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerSession->getCustomerId()); 
            //OR 
            //$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();

            $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
            try {
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_field', $randomletter);
                $customer->updateData($customerData);
                $customer->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::setCustomField()

Comment: Updated ans pls check now.

Comment: Thanks for helping me....but it's not working...

Comment: getDataModel() not working

Comment: `$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();` this row is redundant because repository returns Data Model. Without this row it should work.

Comment: @zhartaunik you're right but then you can't call `->save()` on data model so alternatively `$this->customerRepository->save($customer)` should work but it doesn't save the custom attribute's value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerSession->getCustomerId());
$customer->setCustomAttribute('custom_field',$randomletter);
$customer->save();
```