# Magento2 Customer Attribute

Tags: magento2

I have created customer image attribute and I create form which hit to controller after fill if customer email not exsist it save customer with my custom attribute and values save but if customer exsist then my image attribute not work this is my code:-

```
$customer->setCustomerImageGovtId($file_name);
 $customer->save();
```

Comment: Can this help you? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175613/how-to-save-custom-attribute-value-in-customer-entity-table-using-controller?rq=1

Comment: already tried...